# Opencart File Permission Error on frontend

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I am working on a project hosted at 27littlethings.com and I can't seem to get rid of this error:

> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/a27lifdy/public_html/system/storage/logs/error.php):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/a27lifdy/public_html/system/library/log.php on line 6

I have tried to change the file permissions on the specified file but the problem is not going away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the permissions on the file in question:

```
chmod 755 /home/a27lifdy/public_html/system/storage/logs/error.php
```

or

```
chmod 777 /home/a27lifdy/public_html/system/storage/logs/error.php
```

You can also try just changing the permission on the folder:

```
chmod 777 /home/a27lifdy/public_html/system/storage/logs/
```